# Postscript font to EOT

Tags: post, types, fonts

I have a postscript font in my local language. Now to avoid errors in webpages i need them converted to EOT. How should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: before converting, modifying, or distributing fonts, you should first ensure that your license to the font data allows the activity. Many commercially-available fonts (and even many free-but-not-open-source fonts) have restrictions.

You'll first need to convert the font into TrueType flavor of OpenType. There are a number of free and commercially-available programs and service to do this. Next you will need to convert the TrueType into EOT. There are a few tools as well as services to do this, too, or if you are able to write Win32 code, you can do this using the [TTEmbedFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function(s) with more control over the output.